# Sample a Bivariate Empirical (Kernel) Probability Density Function

Tags: matlab, random

I fitted a mixture gaussian model to a series of x,y data points. Now, I need to sample from that fitted pdf. How should I do this in Matlab? Just by sampling the (empirical) marginal pdf's of the data points? Here's a plot of the fitted pdf:

[image]

Comment: Since the model you are using is a GMM, you could follow these instructions: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/36174

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks! Following the link yuo sent, I also found the command Y = random(obj,n) in Matlab... which seems to work nicely..

Comment: Btw, a more generic approach would involve finding the inverse of the cumulative distribution function and evaluating this function with points drawn uniformly from [0,1]. The resulting values are distributed according to the original probability density function.